# SQL query finds nothing, but returns 1 row with all nulls

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join

I have this query:

```
select problems.problem_id , creator_member_id , problem_title , problem_description , sum( vote ) as totalVotes , DAYOFMONTH(problem_date) , DAYNAME(problem_date) , YEAR(problem_date) , MONTH(problem_date) , first_name , last_name , email , small_thumb , mid_thumb 
    from problems 
        left join problem_votes 
            on problems.problem_id = problem_votes.problem_id 
        left join users 
            on problems.creator_member_id = users.user_id 
        left join member_photo 
            on problems.creator_member_id = member_photo.member_id 
    where problems.problem_id = 1;
```

It matches nothing, and returns this:

```
-+--------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| problem_id | creator_member_id | problem_title | problem_description | totalVotes | DAYOFMONTH(problem_date) | DAYNAME(problem_date) | YEAR(problem_date) | MONTH(problem_date) | first_name | last_name | email | small_thumb | mid_thumb |
+------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+-------+-------------+-----------+
|       NULL |              NULL | NULL          | NULL                |       NULL |                     NULL | NULL                  |               NULL |                NULL | NULL       | NULL      | NULL  | NULL        | NULL      |
+------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+-------+-------------+-----------+
```

But I wonder why it returns anything at all? Is there something wrong with the schema? Or the query?

I am checking whether it returns nothing, and trying to return 404 page, but the system thinks there is 1 returned row, so it confuses my application.

Anything I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can't see how it would return anything since you're explicitly forcing it to return only rows where problems.problem_id = 1.

Comment: @MarcB yeah me too - pretty weird, right? :)

Comment: I believe this has something to do with using aggregate functions like `sum` without a `group by` clause. Adding a `group by` clause may fix it, or you may also need to change your criteria to `having` instead of `where`. (Or I may be totally wrong.)

Comment: I think it has to do something with the sum( vote ) as totalVotes in the select clause

Comment: @grossvogel yes you are right. When I take out that clause, it returns empty as expected.  But the problem is that I need it to count still, lol - any way to get around this issue?

Comment: @GeekedOut: Try adding `GROUP BY problems.problem_id, creator_member_id, problem_title, problem_description, problem_date, first_name, last_name, email, small_thumb ,mid_thumb` at the end of the query. My usual practice is that every column that is in `select` but not aggregated (like `vote`) must be in the `group by` clause. (see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244169/mysql-1140-mixing-of-group-columns)

Comment: @GeekedOut - That wouldn't help you - you don't know if the given id should be present, or is simply bad input data.  So you _shouldn't_ count the 'votes' as 0 - the proper answer is `null` (or perhaps a 'not found exception).  If the id is coming from somewhere else, what happened to your referential integrity?

Comment: @grossvogel that seems to have worked.  If you want, post it as an answer and I'll accept it :) Thank you!

Comment: @X-Zero good point regarding the referential integrity. In this case the db setup isn't optimal, so if there is nothing matched on problem_id then there isn't much to return in that page anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following clause to the end of your query:

```
GROUP BY problems.problem_id, creator_member_id, problem_title, 
problem_description, problem_date, first_name, last_name, 
email, small_thumb ,mid_thumb
```

Best practice is that every column that is selected but not aggregated (like vote) must be in the group by clause, though MYSQL does not enforce this. Instead, it behaves strangely and confuses people. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854350/14957) for a better explanation.)

Comment: This was my problem exactly. Coming from a PostgreSQL background, I was used to the DB not letting me be sloppy...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to

```
sum( vote ) as totalVotes
```

If you want to use an  aggregate functions as SUM to group the result-set you have to use a
statement as GROUP BY.

And if you want to filter that result you should use HAVING

http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/04/group-by-having-sum-avg-and-count.html

In your case i think this should work:

```
SELECT problems.problem_id , creator_member_id , problem_title , problem_description , SUM( vote ) AS totalVotes , 
DAYOFMONTH(problem_date) , DAYNAME(problem_date) , YEAR(problem_date) , MONTH(problem_date) , first_name , last_name , email , small_thumb , mid_thumb 
FROM problems 
    LEFT JOIN problem_votes 
        ON problems.problem_id = problem_votes.problem_id 
    LEFT JOIN users 
        ON problems.creator_member_id = users.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN member_photo 
        ON problems.creator_member_id = member_photo.member_id
 WHERE problems.problem_id = 1; 
GROUP BY problems.problem_id , creator_member_id , problem_title , problem_description , problem_date , first_name , last_name , email , small_thumb , mid_thumb
```

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure you do not have a row that with all NULL

Then: The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).

Try change it to INNER JOIN

Comment: The WHERE clause is filtering `problems.problem_id`, which is a value in the left most table in the joins.  Yet the results show NULL for `problems.problem_id`.  Changing to INNER JOIN should have no effect here.  I suspect the issue is outside of the SQL itself.