# How to show column name and nested aggregation result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a nested aggregation where I can choose whether aggregate the max, min, or avg of a nested avg aggregation.

I want my result to look like this: (genre, MAX or MIN or AVG of nested AVG)

Current i have a nested aggregation query which only returns the Maximum average price of a genre, but i can't seem to also select the genre corresponding to that maximum.

Consider the table **games(gameID, gameName, genre, price)**, disregard gameID and gameName.

The nested query i have right now:

```
SELECT MAX(avggenreprice) AS maxavg
FROM    (
    SELECT genre as subgenre, AVG(price) as avggenreprice
    FROM games
    GROUP BY 
        subgenre
) AS sub;
```

Example result of this query:

```
|maxavg|

| 368.22|
```

I want it to look like this

```
| genre | maxavg |

| Racer | 368.22 |
```

Ive tried :

```
SELECT sub.subgenre, MAX(avggenreprice) AS maxavg
FROM    (
    SELECT genre as subgenre, AVG(price) as avggenreprice
    FROM games
    GROUP BY 
        subgenre
    ) AS sub
;
```

But this just gives me error code 1140

Comment: In your outer select just add what you wanna select ... so just add that "genre" column and if you wanna select just first result from inner select, use top 1

Comment: @Veljko89 I've tried, it gives me Error code 1140

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 1  subgenre AS genre ,  AVG (price) As maxavg   from games  
group by  subgenre order  by AVG (price) desc
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subgenre, avggenreprice AS maxavg
FROM    (
    SELECT genre as subgenre, AVG(price) as avggenreprice
    FROM games
    GROUP BY 
        subgenre
) AS sub 
ORDER BY avggenreprice DESC 
Limit 1;
```

The 1140 code arises when MySQL is not sure how to process an aggregate function, and requires an explicit GROUP BY clause. See ([MySQL #1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244169/mysql-1140-mixing-of-group-columns)).

The simplest solution for your case is to replace the aggregate function max with sort DESC and limit 1 clauses.

Comment: This returns several rows, which is no different than just running the inner aggregation. This doesnt work :(

Comment: Thats because theres more than one genre. Are you looking for the subgenre with the max average price instead?

Comment: Sorry, didnt read closely, the edited code above should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  A subquery is not necessary:

```
SELECT genre as subgenre, AVG(price) as avggenreprice
FROM games
GROUP BY subgenre
ORDER BY avggenreprice DESC
LIMIT 1;
```