# Eloquent getting Syntax error or access violation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

in `laravel 5` when in try to implementing this sql command which **i don't get any error** on `phpmyadmin` :

```
SELECT shoppings.*, sum(shoppings.ordering_count) 
FROM `shoppings` join products on products.id = shoppings.product_id 
where `shoppings`.`user_ordering_ip` = '127.0.0.1'
```

with this query on laravel as:

```
$userShoppings = \DB::table('shoppings')
    ->join('products', 'shoppings.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select('*', \DB::raw('sum(shoppings.ordering_count)'))
    ->where('shoppings.user_ordering_ip', "'".request()->ip()."'")
    ->get();
```

i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of 
GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is 
illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL #1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244169/mysql-1140-mixing-of-group-columns)

Comment: Is the below working for you ? i mean adding groupBy ?

Comment: @Maraboc no it doesn't work for me

Comment: try with  `->groupBy('shoppings.id')` !

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy :Try my updated answer

Comment: @Maraboc : May be he wants sum of all rows, using `groupBy` would definitely fix this problem but result sum will not be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following query, without `'` quotes here `request()->ip`, I doubt you are not calling `ip()` method here, and also dont use `sum` method here

```
$userShoppings = \DB::table('shoppings as s')
    ->join('products as p', 's.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->select('p.*','s.*')
    ->where('s.user_ordering_ip', request()->ip())
    ->get();

$sum_of_ordering_count = $userShoppings->sum('ordering_count');
```

Comment: what error ? share error ? and I updated `->ip()` to `->ip`

Comment: this error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP`

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy : use $sum_of_ordering_count = $userShoppings->sum('ordering_count');

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is correct.

You can try with below Query Code.

```
$userShoppings = \DB::table('shoppings')
    ->join('products', 'shoppings.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select('shoppings.*', \DB::raw('sum(shoppings.ordering_count)'))
    ->where('shoppings.user_ordering_ip', '=', '127.0.0.1')
    ->get();
```

Also it seems there is may be error on `request()->ip`